# latex beamer appendix numbering

Tags: beamer, numbering, appendices

Why are the slides from appendix not numbered with letters?

Is there a solution?

Thank you for your help

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\section{test1}
\begin{frame}{\insertsectionnumber.~\insertsection}
 bal bla
\end{frame}

\appendix

\section{test2}
\begin{frame}{\insertsectionnumber.~\insertsection}
 bla bla
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is so, because `\insertsectionnumber` is defined as (in the file `beamerbasesection.sty`)

```
\def\insertsectionnumber{\@arabic\c@section}
```

And `\appendix` doesn't change this;

```
\newcommand<>\appendix{%
  \only#1{\part{\appendixname}
  \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@appendixpages{\the\c@page}}}}}
```

so the counter will appear using arabic representation.

You can change this, redefining `\insertsectionnumber` in the proper location:

```
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand\insertsectionnumber{\Alph{section}}
```

Perhaps you want to let \appendix do this change:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand<>\appendix{%
\setcounter{section}{0}%
\renewcommand\insertsectionnumber{\Alph{section}}%
  \only#1{\part{\appendixname}
  \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@appendixpages{\the\c@page}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{test1}
\begin{frame}{\insertsectionnumber.~\insertsection}
 bal bla
\end{frame}

\appendix

\section{test2}
\begin{frame}{\insertsectionnumber.~\insertsection}
 bla bla
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does the `<>` do in `\renewcommand<>{\appendix{…}}`?  Is that a beamer-ism?  (I'd expect it to mean an overlay specification in the body of the document, but am not sure how to make sense of it in the preamble.)